# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /drupal on this server Drupal 8

Tags: composer-php, localhost, wamp, drupal-8

I installed files for Drupal 8.6.1 via Composer on my local machine (Windows 7, Wampstack-7.1.18-1, Apache 2). And then to proceed with installation and tweak the Drupal site, I can't reach the page in browser by link http://localhost/~/drupal/. It displays an error:

> 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /drupal on this server

Meanwhile, I can reach any other projects on the localhost, which aren't developed with Drupal. All properties for Drupal folder are on maximum.

Could anybody help with the issue, I dug the whole internet and haven't found a solution. Thanks in advance!